# Is there any way in laravel 5.4 to track how many time spent by login user?

Tags: laravel-5, timer

Hi All Master Laravel,

I need your help to get data timespent from login user in laravel, I'm using Sentinel for login and Laravel 5.4

If only one page, we can use TimeOut javascript, but what I need is log for user which spent all page in my website

Regards,
Sidik

Answer (score 0):

As I know there is no built-in solution for your purpose.

But you can write your personal implementation based on data from user requests.

Also, you can use third party service for this purpose too, for example [Google Analytics](https://analytics.google.com). Here is [an example](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123666?hl=en) how to set up the user ID into your analytics code.

Comment: note that you cannot fetch data back from their API with the user ID, it's something you can only give to Google, but not retrieve via API.